# IBM Worklight 5.0.5 method error in an uploaded javascript file

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I have an issue when deploying my app on server :

[image]

Why not, but here is the problem :

- the JS file containing the method is present on the server 
  [image]
- this JS file is included in the **appName.html** file
  [image]
- there is no error in this JS file
- there is no synthax error between the method and its call

The question is : why this error since I think all has been made to work fine.

Any help would be great

version : *Worklight 5.0.5.20130115-0926*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only if the javascript source is included directly in the document that you can utilize functions that has not already been defined.

Just import the cxf-utils.js before you import the user-uploaded file.

Comment: This method call is done via a button, I just switched (in my .html file) the two imports. Didn't think it could generate an error, as these methods aren't used until all is loaded.